# Bevel problem (im new to blender)

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I recently got to blender and while trying out the bevel modifier on a cube i couldnt get what i wanted. I am using blender 3.3.1.

So i wanted this:
[image]

But i can only get this: [image]

How do i fix it? and also, how do i get this type of thing where there are 2 flat surfaces?:
[image]

Comment: The object is beveling "weird" because you scaled the cube in object mode (Scaling in edit mode is usually preferable because it maintains the objects' _global_ scale). However, if you do scale in object mode, you can select the object (in object mode), then press Ctrl+A and select "scale" to reset it. You can get the flat top and bottoms by weight painting them and then selecting "weight" as the limiting factor in the bevel modifier (or in the case of the bottom image. you could just select the 4 side edges of a cube then bevel with Ctrl+B, drag the mouse out and scroll up a couple of times).

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)